# Loading Bar while Rendering in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-material

I am using Angular JS, Angular JS material design library for UI and `ui-router` for routing. So `ui-router` provides events on which I can listen for state changes and view-loading which will be fired at root scope ( events like `stateChangeStart`, `stateChangeSuccess`, `viewContentLoading`, `viewContentLoaded`).

So they must be defined as `.run()` time before the actual execution begins but how can I use them in controller so that each time a state is resolving or a view is rendering I can show a progress bar specified in material design library?

I am new to this so any advice or more common way would be appreciated. Currently I'm using `ngprogress` library for state transition and its working fine but I need to use it for view rendering.

I am defining this at `.run()` here. Is there any other way besides this?

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(evt, to, params) {         

    if($rootScope.progressbar) {
        $rootScope.progressbar.complete();
    }

    $rootScope.progressbar = ngProgressFactory.createInstance();
    $rootScope.progressbar.start();

    $rootScope.loadingView = true;

    if (to.$$route && to.$$route.resolve) {  
      $rootScope.loadingView = true;
    }

    if (to.redirectTo) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      $state.go(to.redirectTo, params)
    }
});

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(evt, to, params) { 
    $rootScope.progressbar.complete();
});
```

Comment: You don't need to do that in the `run()` function. You can inject the `$rootScope` anywhere you want. Try adding an own directive that handles this.

Comment: I tried. `viewContentLoading` dosen't work.